# read a certificate from sdcard and put in byte(android)

Tags: android

Need a function like this in java in Android Eclipse

```
Path Path = Paths.get ("sdcard / certificado.crt");
byte [] = certificado Files.readAllBytes (caminho);
```

I need to read a certificate from `sdcard` and put in byte to send via socket to served, does anyone know some code for this in android Studio, Eclipse?

Comment: please use English only

Comment: why your question title is in English but not the question.

Comment: "sdcard / certificado" is almost certainly incorrect as a path name.